# Resolution of ODE Cauchy problem with delay

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

We have the following ODE with delay
$$
du(t)/dt= au(t-\tau) - bu(t), 
$$
$$
u(t)=u_0: -\tau < t < 0
$$
How we can calculate the solution of this problem? Please
The delay make this problem so complicated for me

Thank you for the help

Comment: What did you find? Can you give the solutions on the initial intervals $[0,τ)$, $[τ,2τ)$, $[2τ,3τ)$? Can you guess a pattern there?

Comment: I can do this in the case tau =0. But in the case tau not 0 I haven’ idea to find the solution u(t)

Comment: The first term is then just a known solution, so on $[0,τ)$ you solve $u'(t)+bu(t)=au_0$. With that solution you can then find what the solution on $[τ,2τ)$ is and so on.

Comment: I write what i try in an answer. Can you help me please

Comment: I would first try the case where $a,b$ are constants. If these coefficients are functions, then an explicit symbolic general solution becomes less likely.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to obtain an approximate solution for small $\tau$?.

Hint.

After transforming Laplace we have

$$
sU(s)-u(0) = a\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}u(t-\tau)dt-bU(s)
$$

but

$$
\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}u(t-\tau)dt=e^{-\tau s}\int_{-\tau}^{\infty}e^{-s\xi}u(\xi)d\xi=e^{-\tau s}\left(\int_{-\tau}^{0}e^{-s\xi}u_0d\xi+U(s)\right)=e^{-\tau s}\left(\frac{u_0}{s}\left(e^{s\tau}-1\right)+U(s)\right)
$$

so we have

$$
sU(s)= ae^{-\tau s}\left(\frac{u_0}{s}\left(e^{s\tau}-1\right)+U(s)\right)+bU(s)+u_0
$$

or

$$
U(s) = \frac{1}{s-b-a e^{-\tau s}}\left(ae^{\tau s}\left(\frac{u_0}{s}\left(e^{s\tau}-1\right)\right)+u_0\right)
$$

now for small $\tau$ we can use the Padé approximation $e^{\tau s}\approx \frac{1+\frac{s \tau }{2}}{1-\frac{s \tau }{2}}$ and after that, we have

$$
U(s) = \frac{u_0 (2 a \tau +s \tau +2)}{s \tau  (a-b+s)-2 (a+b-s)}
$$

or

$$
U(s) = \frac{c_2}{s+r_1}+\frac{c_3}{s+r_2}
$$

here $r_1,r_2$ are the roots of $s \tau  (a-b+s)-2 (a+b-s)=0$

making the inversion, we have a quantitative-qualitative way to study it's behavior.

EDIT

Considering the denominator of $\frac{1}{s-b-a e^{-\tau s}}$ we can make considerations concerning the $u(t)$ behavior. The zeros of $s-b-a e^{-\tau s}$ will dictate if the solution is a stable solution or not. To have a stable solution is sufficient that the roots of $s-b-a e^{-\tau s}=0$ be inside the left half complex plane: then making $s=x+iy$ we have

$$
\cases{
x-b-a e^{-\tau x}\cos(\tau y) = 0\\
y+a e^{-\tau x}\sin(\tau y) = 0 
}\ \ \ \ (1)
$$

Supposing $a=1,b=5,\tau=10$ we have a root location map as follows. The intersections between the red and blue curves are the solutions for $s-b-ae^{-\tau s}=0$. In this case the solution $u(t)$ is limited for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ because all poles are inside the left complex plane.

[image]

[image]

Comparing with $a=2,b=1,\tau = 2$ we can see that in this case the solution is unlimited because it has a pole into the right half complex plane.

[image]

[image]

EDIT-2

As a general rule, from $(1)$ we obtain

$$
\Phi(x,y) = \left(\frac{x-b}{a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{a}\right)^2-e^{-2\tau x}=0
$$

so a sufficient condition for stability is that the curve $\Phi(x,y)$  were contained into the left half complex plane. In the previous plots, $\Phi(x,y)=0$ appears as a dashed black trace.

Comment: Cesareo. I don’t undertsand your solution. Why tau must to be small? And how we deduce u(t)? Please

Comment: $\tau$ must be small to validate the Padé approximation. But first: did you have learned yet the Laplace transform? This is the first step to understand the solution.

Comment: $\tau$ is not small in my problem.

Comment: Then a higher order Pade approximation will be required.

Comment: Can you help me please ton understand how we found the expression of the solution u(t). Please can you write an complete answer? (I know how we apply Laplace operator then we can not write this point).

Comment: Included the inversion form for the present Padé approximation.

Comment: In the case of my problem, we use de Padé approximation $$e^{s \tau} \equiv 1+ \dfrac{s\tau}{1- \dfrac{1/2 s\tau}{1+1/6 s \tau}}$$. It's ok? If it's ok, please how we can write u(t) using $\phi$ and $\psi$? I don't understand how we find the final expression of $u(t)$. Thank's in advance for the help

Comment: Cesareo please, what do you means by "making the inversion, we have a quantitative-qualitative way to study it's behavior."? Please when you say that $\tau$ is small, if $\tau=10$ for example, is it considered small? Finally, please can you give me some detail of calculate $u(t)$? I failled to obtain the same expression of $u(t)$ as you find. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Included a new edit.

Comment: Thank you so much Cesareo. Please can you send me the details of calculuc of $u(t)$ afiter substitution of Padé approximation? I don't found the same results. Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Included an intermediate step before inversion.

Comment: Cesareo thank you so much. Please I have a last request. Can you give some lines of calculus of inversion Laplace of U(s)? How we decompose U(s) to obtain u(t)? Please. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Included one step more.

Comment: Cesareo: Thank you so much. I have a last question about the graphic of the solution u(t). In the case: tau=2, b=1, a=2, u0=4.5. What’s the graph of u(t) you obtain? It haven’t the same behaviour in this case. No?

Comment: I think that there is an error beacause if $\tau=2$, $a=2$ and $b=1$, $\phi$ is not good defined

Comment: Thank you Cesareo. You add the graphic of the solution u but please what’s the expression of solution u(t)? You remove it on the aswer.